# Filtering non MySQL Latin1 Characters from a String in Java

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a MySQL table that uses latin1, unfortunately I cannot change this.

Before inserting Strings into this table I would like to check if a String contains a character that is not part of the latin1 character set. This way I can remove it from my data set.

How can I do this?

e.g

```
boolean hasNonLatin1Chars = string.chars()
                .anyMatch(c -> ...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it simple and robust, take advantage of `CharsetEncoder` :

```
/** replaces any invalid character in Latin1 by the character rep */
public static String latin1(String str, char rep) {
    CharsetEncoder cs = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.newEncoder()
            .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
            .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
            .replaceWith(new byte[] { (byte) rep });
    try {
        ByteBuffer b = cs.encode(CharBuffer.wrap(str));
        return new String(b.array(), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); // should not happen
    }
}
```

This will replace each invalid charset in ISO_8859_1 (= Latin1) by the replacement character `rep` (which, of course, should be a valid Latin1 char).

If you are ok with the default replacement (`'?'`), you can make it simpler:

```
public static String latin1(String str) {
    return new String(str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
          StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
}
```

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String x = "hi Œmar!";
    System.out.println("'" + x + "' -> '" + latin1(x,'?') + "'");
}
```

outputs  `'hi Œmar!' -> 'hi ?mar!'`

A possible drawback of this approach is that only allows you to replace each invalid character by a single replacement character - you cannot remove it or use a multi-character sequence.
If you want this, and if are reasonably sure that some character will never appear in your string, you can go for the usual dirty tricks - for example, assuming the `\u0000` will never appear:

```
/* removes invalid Latin1 charaters - assumes the zero character never appears */
public static String latin1removeinvalid(String str) {
    return latin1(str,(char)0).replace("\u0000", "");
}
```

---

Added: if you only want to check for validity, then it's simpler:

```
public static boolean isValidLatin1(String str) {
    return StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.newEncoder().canEncode(str);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked great. I only really needed to work out *if* there was invalid characters but I can just do an equality check afterwards like in other answers :)

Comment: @Edd : if you only want to check for validity, then it's simpler - see update

Answer (score 0):

If your source data is consistently UTF8, then say so.  Then you get the best of both worlds -- UTF8 characters that have a transliteration to latin1 will be changed; those that don't will come out as '?'.

Use this in the `getConnection()` call:

```
?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

No testing for bad characters, no conversion in your code.  MySQL does all the work automagically.

Answer (score -1):

The [Basic Latin range](http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php) is `0020–007F`, so you could check if trying to replace the first instance of a non-latin character matches the original `String`:

```
boolean hasNonLatin1Chars = string.equals((string.replaceFirst("[^\\u0020-\\u007F]", "")));
```

This will return `false` if it contains a non-latin character.

There is Latin-1 Supplement (`00A0 — 00FF`), Latin Extended-A (`0100 — 017F`) and Latin Extended-B (`0180 — 024F`) so you can modify the range if necessary.